# reduce duplicate queries in django modelform

Tags: python, django, query-optimization, query-performance

I have a modelform to create model instances in my function based views.
When create view renders the form template, it runs 6 queries which I want to reduce.
Is there any way I can reduce qs or increase model create view's performance?

**models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='teachers',
                              default='teacheravatar.jpg')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expertise = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=Topic, blank=True, related_name='expert_in')
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    joining_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['joining_date', 'name']
```

*** forms.py ***

```
class TeacherForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ['name', 'photo', 'date_of_birth',
                  'designation', 'expertise',
                  'mobile', 'email', ]
```

*** views.py ***

```
# THIS VIEW DUPLICATES QUEREIS
# AND RUNS 6 QUERIES
@login_required
def add_teacher_view(request):
    """
    :param request:
    :return: teacher add form
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeacherForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            pk = form.instance.pk
            return redirect('teachers:teacher_details', pk=pk)
    form = TeacherForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'teachers/add_teacher.html', context)
```

Comment: You need to tell us what these queries are.

Comment: Actually I'm so weak in sql, I'm tracing queries with django-debug-toolbar.

Comment: you can see it here: https://pasteboard.co/IJ5eLmS.png

Answer (score 2):

you should define .choices on Relationship fields. when you have Relationship fields in modelform, django modelform fields run duplicate queries in request.get method. in fact we prevent fields running duplicate queries by providing data manually.

**models.py**

```
class TeacherForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ['name', 'photo', 'date_of_birth',
                  'designation', 'expertise',
                  'mobile', 'email', ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        designation_choices = [(designation.id, designation.__str__()) for designation in Designation.objects.all()]
        expertise_choices = [(topic.id, topic.__str__()) for topic in Topic.objects.all()] 
        self.fields['designation'].choices = designation_choices
        self.fields['expertise'].choices = expertise_choices
```

i recommend you define **str** in your all models, for example suppose you return self.name in **str** of all your models, you can define designation_choices and expertise_choices like this:

```
        designation_choices = Designation.objects.values_list('id', 'name')
        expertise_choices = Topic.objects.values_list('id', 'name')
```

this is so faster because instead querying all fields of Designation or Topic querying only two fields of them.

### more deeper

**(answer by referencing to django course code, just for more read)**:

django modelform create form fields ModelChoiceField, ModelMultipleChoiceField for ForeignKey, ManyToManyField fields. both of these fields use method _get_choices for creating those duplicated queries.

duplicated queries run by self.iterator(self) the key here is when _choices is provided default querying(duplicated queries) will stop. property choices here will fill variable _choices and remove duplicated queries.

**django.forms.models.py**

```
    def _get_choices(self):
        # If self._choices is set, then somebody must have manually set
        # the property self.choices. In this case, just return self._choices.
        if hasattr(self, '_choices'):
            return self._choices

        # Otherwise, execute the QuerySet in self.queryset to determine the
        # choices dynamically. Return a fresh ModelChoiceIterator that has not been
        # consumed. Note that we're instantiating a new ModelChoiceIterator *each*
        # time _get_choices() is called (and, thus, each time self.choices is
        # accessed) so that we can ensure the QuerySet has not been consumed. This
        # construct might look complicated but it allows for lazy evaluation of
        # the queryset.
        return self.iterator(self)

    choices = property(_get_choices, ChoiceField._set_choices)
```